# Comparison of single values in xts and data frame fails

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I am attempting to compare two  values in `xts`, by subsetting the specific positions of the values. Since I cannot get the result in `xts` I have tried to extract the `coredata()` into a data frame. The comparison in the data frame fails also.

**Question:** Why does it fail to perform the comparison in `xts` and data frame?

**Temp solution:** Extract the values into vectors and compare them. It is not a solution since I need to compare many values in a big xts/dataframe.

**Wanted solution:** I need to be able to compare values, by subsetting in both xts and dataframe. This should be done without loading more packages then having dataframe from R core, and installing `xts`.

Below you see the different variations of my attempts:

```
#########################################
# Create dataframe [df1]
#########################################
date <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-10-01 09:01:00", "2018-10-01 09:02:00"))
open                     <- c(0, 1)
high                     <- c(0, 4)
low                      <- c(0, 3)
close                    <- c(0, 6) 

df1 <- data.frame(
  date,
  open,
  high,
  low,
  close
)

#############
# Create xts1
#############
# Build an xts based on dataframe components
xts1 <- xts(df1[-1], order.by=df1[,1])

##########################################################
# Attempt 1 to compare xts(column2,row2 with column3,row2)
##########################################################
isTRUE(xts1[2,2] > xts1[2,3]) # Returns false, why?
  # Tests:
  xts1[2,2] # Not stored, just for printout confirmation.
  xts1[2,3] # Not stored, just for printout confirmation.
  isTRUE(4 > 3) # Returns true, correct.


####################################
# Attempt 2 - move xts to dataframe.
####################################
df1 <- coredata(xts1)
isTRUE(df1[2,2] > df1[2,3]) # Returns false, why?
  # Tests:
  df1[2,2] # Not stored, just for printout confirmation.
  df1[2,3] # Not stored, just for printout confirmation.

###################################################
# Attempt 3 - move xts to dataframe, extract values
###################################################
df2 <- coredata(xts1)
extracted.value.1 <- as.numeric(df2[2,2]) # Extract value
extracted.value.2 <-as.numeric(df2[2,3]) # Extract value
isTRUE(extracted.value.1 > extracted.value.2) # Returns true, correct.
```

Here is the info from `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.11-2 zoo_1.8-4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4  tools_3.4.4     grid_3.4.4      lattice_0.20-35
```

Result of dput(xts1)

```
structure(c(0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 6), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("open", "high", "low", "close")), index = structure(c(1538377260, 
1538377320), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
```

Result of dput(df1)

```
structure(c(0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 6), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("open", "high", "low", "close")))
```

Comment: `isTRUE(xts1[2,2] > xts1[2,3])` returns `TRUE` on my end.

Comment: @AkselA: I took the code from the question and copied into a blank R file and sourced in Rstudio.  I then run the [isTRUE] by copying from your comment. I do get still retun FALSE.

Comment: `isTRUE(df1[2,2] > df1[2,3])` also returns `TRUE`. Restart R, load only `xts` and the code in your question and see what you get.

Comment: can we see `sessionInfo()` from a clean R session?

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I added the [sessionInfo()] at the end of the question. Closing down R / Rstudio and will taek a new [sessionInfo()].

Comment: That's a slightly old `xts` version. You might update it, but I doubt that will resolve anything. Retry in a fresh workplace would be the obvious next step. If you could post the output from `dput(xts1)` and `dput(df1)`, that might also be helpful.

Comment: I have `xts` 0.11-2,  `zoo` 1.8-4 and (like @AkselA) your first example is working for me ...

Comment: Looking through the `xts` [NEWS](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/blob/master/NEWS), there are some references to subsetting issues that have been fixed. Worth trying an update I think.

Comment: I closed R / Rstudio, unloaded all packages, but kept xts, zoo, methods and utils, since it seems that remove any of the packages destroys the setup. Still get FALSE. Updated the [sessionInfo()]

Comment: Tried now without Rstudio, just load the same environment into R terminal and run isTRUE(xts1[2,2] > xts1[2,3]). Still returns FALSE.

Comment: Added result of dput(xts1) and dput(df1) at the end of the question.

Comment: Updated xts package, updated sessionInfo() in question. Still return FALSE.

Comment: Using your `xts1` I still get `TRUE`. Seems like installing `xts 0.11-2` is the nest port of call.

Comment: Updated package zoo, updated sessionInfo(). Still returns FALSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! It's an R-version problem, not an `xts`-version problem.

This is a known "infelicity" in `isTRUE()`, described [here](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/06/r-tip-use-istrue/) and fixed after version 3.5.

> Note: prior to R 3.5 isTRUE (the current version!) was defined as “isTRUE <- function(x) identical(x, TRUE)” (please see change-log [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)). This seemed clever, but failed on named logical values (violating a principle of least surprise):

You can update R, or redefine `isTRUE` as

```
isTRUE <- function(x) { is.logical(x) && length(x) == 1 && !is.na(x) && x }
```

or use `isTRUE(unname(x),unname(y))`. Here's what the current version of `?isTRUE` says:

> ‘isTRUE(x)’ is the same as ‘{ is.logical(x) && length(x) == 1 &&
>        !is.na(x) && x }’; ‘isFALSE()’ is defined analogously.
>        Consequently, ‘if(isTRUE(cond))’ may be preferable to ‘if(cond)’
>        because of ‘NA’s.
>        In earlier R versions, ‘isTRUE <- function(x) identical(x, TRUE)’,
>        had the drawback to be false e.g., for ‘x <- c(val = TRUE)’.

Comment: Started with redefining. Now both [isTRUE] for xts and dataframe are returning TRUE. I need to check if I should upgrade R version. After having redefined, can I reverse to get the original problem back? I would need to have the problem in place, when upgrading R version, to verify that problem disappears after installing new R version

Comment: if you `rm(isTRUE)` you will remove your custom-defined version, restoring the problem (as long as you are running R < 3.5.0).

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: I have now update R base to 3.5.2 and all tests in question pass, resulting in returning value [TRUE]. Setting SO answer to approved.